# Homebrew can't install Watchman: No similarly named formulae found | MacOS Big Sur

Tags: npm, homebrew, watchman

Homebrew error screen capture

[image]

Anybody know why my Homebrew can't install any packages and keep showing this error?

I've tried to install watchman but homebrew shows me this error, then I tried to install other packages but still, this error shows up. I already tried to install and reinstall homebrew using `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall.sh)`.

Please help

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/install.html#installing-on-macos-or-linux-via-homebrew

Comment: I already did it but still showing the error like the image above @ShrihanKumarPadhy

Comment: Does `brew update && brew tap homebrew/core && brew install --HEAD watchman` work?

Comment: Still doesn't work :( @ShrihanKumarPadhy something is off with homebrew in big sur

Answer (score 20):

enter this

`brew doctor`

and then this

`git -C $(brew --repo homebrew/core) checkout master`

same error, fix already now

Comment: I did exactly what u told me to do but I still can't install any package with Homebrew

Answer (score 0):

rm -fr $(brew --repo homebrew/cask)

brew tap homebrew/cask

then check brew doctor gives error again

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. Turns out I had smooth brain and had just ended the Homebrew installation before it was complete, because it looked like it had stopped and I assumed it was complete.

To resolve it, I uninstalled Homebrew, removed the whole Homebrew directory, reinstalled it using the install_brew.sh file from the github, and made sure to let the full install finish and return me to the command line. Then installing watchman worked as expected.

Answer (score -2):

first type

```
brew doctor
```

and then this

```
git -C $(brew --repo homebrew/core) checkout master
```